# Restrict ap-hotspot to connect to a fixed number of devices or only to known devices

Tags: wireless, internet, android

I use `ap-hotspot` (http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)  to share LAN connection on my Ubuntu PC to my Android mobile. I want to know if I can restrict the connection to only a fixed number of devices or give the device ID list and ask it to connect only to the devices in the list. Is this possible